# Incompatible types. Found java.lang.Class<capture<?>>, required char,byte,short,int

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am writing a mock class that can set field value according to its type by using reflection (which I didn't find any). Then I realize an interesting phenomena:

```java
public void play(Class c)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, 
               InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {

    Constructor declaredConstructor = c.getDeclaredConstructor();
    Object o = declaredConstructor.newInstance();
    Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field f : fields) {
        String name = f.getName();
        Class<?> type = f.getType();
        switch (type) { // switch block
            case String.class:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (type.equals(String.class)) { // if block
            f.set(o, name);
        } else if (type.equals(Integer.class)) {
            f.set(o, nextInteger());
        }

    }
}
```

`switch` block gives error:

> Incompatible types. Found java.lang.Class<capture<?>>, required char,byte,short,int,Character,Byte,Short,Integer,String or an enum'

But `if` block works as expect. I guess the difference is switch works like `==` while if has `equals`. Is it possible to write above logic using `switch`?

Comment: It's not related to `equals` (or String wouldn't work either). The thing is `switch` is a construct with syntax rules associated with it. You can't just use any arbitrary data type with a switch, that's that.

Comment: And comparing it to `if` in that respect is a bit... not fitting. `if` takes only a `boolean` expression. Your own code will do the comparison (as you're doing with `type.equals(String.class)`), but `switch` does the comparison itself, which is why it takes a value expression rather than a boolean. So the two take widely differing ranges of data types.

Comment: @ernest_k OK, then I guess switch takes a few data types, but is that compilation error misleading, which actually should be *Class<?> is not applicable for switch*?

Comment: The compiler error is surely not pretty, but it is not misleading. All wildcard generic type arguments are referred to as `"capture... <something followed by bounds where applicable>"`. It's not specific to switch expressions. It's just related to the data type of your `type` variable.